# Sitecore: Could not find configuration node

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I'm getting the following error when I trying to run my site via IIS:

> Could not find configuration node: settings/setting[@name='MediaFolder']/@value

I'm using version 6.5 of Sitecore. When I search for MediaFolder in my project I find the following:

**SitecoreSettings.config**

```
<setting name="MediaFolder" value="$(mediaFolder)" />
```

**Web.config:**

```
<sc.variable name="mediaFolder" value="/upload" />
```

Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with Sitecore so I'm not really sure where to start looking. Perhaps I'm missing a file?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using? You should check either web.config or /app_config/sitecore.config for a value "MediaFolder".

Comment: Updated the question with the information.

Comment: So you found these config files in your project. But are they deployed to your website instance in IIS? (they probably aren't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for me was a problem with config transformation files that were not correctly specified as transformations.

In my Web.csproj file I had this:

```
<Content Include="App_Config\AppSettings.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</Content>
<Content Include="App_Config\AppSettings.Test.config" />
```

When it should have been this:

```
<Content Include="App_Config\AppSettings.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</Content>
<None Include="App_Config\AppSettings.Test.config">
  <DependentUpon>AppSettings.config</DependentUpon>
  <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
</None>
```

Comment: Can only do it in 2 days.